# Animation using react-spring interpolate function not working

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I am trying to understand how the react-spring interpolation works.

Here is my spring:

```
const { x } = useSpring({ from: { x: 0 }, x: 100, config: { duration: 1000 } })
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
...
return (
  <animated.div style={{
    background: "lightblue",
    height: "100%",
    width: x.interpolate([0, 0.5, 1], [0, 100, 0]).interpolate(x => `${x}%`)
  }} />
)
```

The interpolation happens but it is not rendered.
Here is a sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-panini-fzn54?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Can you help me figure out what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost there. If you want to use range, in the interpolation from `[0, 0.5, 1]` to `[0, 100, 0]` Then you should change the x value between 0 and 1.

So I would change this part:

```
const { x } = useSpring({ from: { x: 0 }, x: 1, config: { duration: 1000 } })
```

I also fixed the codesandbox, but it is a little different it uses the renderprops api.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-varahamihira-6nic7?file=/src/App.js:63-123